# JQuery make added element draggable and save position after dynamically adding

Tags: jquery, append, local-storage

The following code works to make already created elements draggable / resizable and save to localStorage:

```
var positions = JSON.parse(localStorage.positions || "{}");
$(function () {

 //store coordinates of items
  var d = $("[id=draggable]").attr("id", function (i) {
    return "draggable_" + i;
  });
  $.each(positions, function (id, pos) {
    $("#" + id).css(pos);
  });

  d.draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    stack: ".draggable",
    scroll: false,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
      positions[this.id] = ui.position;
      localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions);
    }
  });

  //resizable items
  $(".resizable").resizable({
    minHeight: 50,
    minWidth: 50,
    maxHeight: 500,
    maxWidth: 500,
    aspectRatio: true
  });
});
```

However, I want to add and remove elements dynamically, with the drag / resize / localStorage properties. To add the HTML element, I am currently using append:

```
  $("#htmlexample1").click(function () {
    $("#containment-wrapper").append(
      '<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content draggable"><div class="resizable"><img src="example1.svg" alt="Example1"></div><div class="drag-bottom">Example 1</div></div>'
    );
  });

  $("#htmlexample2").click(function () {
    $("#containment-wrapper").append(
      '<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content draggable"><div class="resizable"><img src="example2.svg" alt="Example2"></div><div class="drag-bottom">Example 2</div></div>'
    );
  });
```

However I understand the previous code is not being applied to this newly created element.  I may have hundreds of items that get dynamically added (like from tool menu) so need concise approach if possible.

How do I apply my localStorage and draggable / resizable properties to each new element that is created?

EDIT:
Tried a suggested solution- I am sure I am missing something as this maintains the original functionality, but does not save new items when page is refreshed.
What  to change to keep new items in local storage?

```
var positions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('positions'));
$(function () {
  var d = $("[id=draggable]").attr("id", function (i) {
    return "draggable_" + i;
  });
  $.each(positions, function (id, pos) {
    $("#" + id).css(pos);
  });
  d.draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    stack: ".draggable",
    scroll: false,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
      positions[this.id] = ui.position;
      localStorage.setItem('positions', JSON.stringify(positions));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: For keeping the draggable properties on new elements, is this something I can use delegate for?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

As I see don't do

```js
localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions);
```

Do for setting an Item

```js
var positions = JSON.stringify(positions);
localStorage.setItem('positions', positions);
```

Or

```js
localStorage.setItem('positions', JSON.stringify(positions));
```

For getting the Item do

```js
var positions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('positions'));
```

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your recommendation with the first solution, but this seems to remove the working functionality.  Items that exist on the page are not being stored in local storage, and new items disappear when the page is refreshed as well.

Comment: The second solution works for keeping the same functionality as I had to begin with - the HTML elements that existed when the page loaded are still present on refresh. But newly created elements are not being kept - that is, they disappear on refresh.